# What does `:-` mean in clojure's core.typed?

Tags: types, clojure

What does `:-` mean in [this code](https://github.com/clojure/core.typed/blob/master/module-check/src/test/clojure/clojure/core/typed/test/rps_async.clj#L101) from the core.typed library?

```
(t/ann play-many [(ta/Chan RPSResult) t/Int -> (t/Map t/Any t/Any)])
(defn play-many
  "Play n matches from out-chan and report a summary of the results."
  [out-chan n]
  (t/loop [remaining :- t/Int, n                          ;; <======== This line
           results :- (t/Map PlayerName t/Int), {}]
    (if (zero? remaining)
      results
      (let [[m1 m2 winner] (a/<!! out-chan)]
        (assert m1)
        (assert m2)
        (assert winner)
        (recur (dec remaining)
               (merge-with + results {winner 1}))))))
```

Comment: It means `:-`. Open up a clojure repl and type `:-` and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned, `:-` is just a keyword. However, in your context it's part of `core.typed`'s annotations, marking loop bindings as being of a specific type:

```
(t/loop [remaining :- t/Int, n
         results :- (t/Map PlayerName t/Int), {}]
  ...)
```

This means that `remaining` is an integer, while `results` is a map associating a player name with an integer. These can be verified using `core.typed`'s type checker.

Answer (score 6):

`:-` is a keyword of a single character, `-`.

```
user=> :-
:-
user=> (class :-)
clojure.lang.Keyword
```